# VHDL Microprocessor 16 bits

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to make a microprocessor architecture and I'm stuck. My accumulator, IR and PC don't seem to be working and I can't figure out why.
their outputs stay always undefined. I check the mapping and the other components of the mp they're are all correct the problem is somewhere in these registers.

```
------------------------------------------------------
--          ALU
------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use work.up_pack.all;

entity alu is 
  port ( A, B : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
          alufs : in ALU_FCTS;
          S : out std_logic_vector( 15 downto 0));
end alu;

architecture arch_alu of alu is
begin
S <= "0000000000000000"; -- sortie par défaut
process(A, B, alufs)
begin
case alufs is
    when ALU_B =>   S <= B;
    when ALU_SUB =>   S <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(B) - unsigned(A));
    when ALU_ADD =>   S <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(B) + unsigned(A));
    when ALU_B_INC =>   S <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(B) + 1);
    when ALU_AND =>   S <= A and B;
    when ALU_OR =>   S <= A or B;
    when ALU_XOR =>   S <= A xor B;
    when others =>   S <= "0000000000000000";
end case;
end process;
end arch_alu;          

------------------------------------------------------
--               ACCUMULATER
------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;


entity accumulator is
  port( clk, raz, load : in std_logic;
        data_in : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_out : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        acc15, accz : out std_logic );
end accumulator;

architecture arch_acc of accumulator is
  signal q_reg : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  begin   
    process(clk)
    begin        
      if rising_edge(clk) then
          if raz='1' then q_reg  <= (others => '0');
          elsif load='1' then q_reg <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(q_reg) + unsigned(data_in));  end if;
    end if;
    end process;
    data_out <= q_reg;
    acc15 <= q_reg(15); 
    accz <= '1' when q_reg = "0000000000000000";
  end arch_acc;
      
------------------------------------------------------
--               REGISTER PC
------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity pc_reg is
  port( clk, raz, load : in std_logic;
        data_in : in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
        data_out : out std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) );
end pc_reg; 

architecture arch_pc_reg of pc_reg is
signal interne : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
  begin   

 process(clk)
        begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if raz='1' then interne <= (others => '0');
            elsif load='1' then interne <= data_in;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    data_out <= interne;
end arch_pc_reg;  
------------------------------------------------------
--                IR (Instruction Register)
------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use work.up_pack.all; 

entity ir_reg is
  port( clk, raz, load : in std_logic;
        data_in : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_out : out std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
        opcode : out OPCODE);
end ir_reg; 

architecture arch_ir_reg of ir_reg is
 signal interne :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin  
 
process(clk)
        begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if raz='1' then data_out <= (others => '0');
            elsif load='1' 
        then 
            data_out <= data_in(11 downto 0);
            interne <= data_in(15 downto 12);
            end if;
        end if;
end process;

opcode <= OP_LDA when interne="0000" else
          OP_STO when interne="0001" else
          OP_ADD when interne="0010" else
          OP_SUB when interne="0011" else
          OP_JMP when interne="0100" else
          OP_JGE when interne="0101" else
          OP_JNE when interne="0110" else
          OP_STP when interne="0111" else
          OP_AND when interne="1000" else
          OP_OR  when interne="1001" else
          OP_XOR when interne="1010" else
          OP_LDR when interne="1011" else
          OP_LDI when interne="1100" else
          OP_STI when interne="1101" else                
          OP_JSR when interne="1110" else
          OP_RET when interne="1111" else
          OP_UNKNOWN;
end arch_ir_reg;
```

Comment: Difficult to say exactly whats wrong without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Did you connect all inputs to something in the testbench?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? A [mcve] would provide the error message(s) as well as the means to reproduce them.

Comment: I testing with forcing variables. I know it's not a good practice but I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a testbench for you to work with. Your accumulator seems to work fine. I tested it with the testbench below. Use it as resource for writing testbenches for the rest of your modules. (You can write a test bench to test all the modules together or individually, just FYI)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity tb_accumulator is
end tb_accumulator;

architecture behav of tb_accumulator is
signal clk : std_logic := '0';
signal raz : std_logic := '1';
signal load : std_logic := '0';
signal data_in : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal data_out : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal acc15 : std_logic := '0';
signal accz : std_logic := '0';

begin
--Assign values for signals being passed into accumulator. 
clk <=  not clk after 2.5 ns;
data_in <= "0000000000000001";
raz <= '0' after 90 ns; --You can do this instead of forcing a signal. Set at what times you want it to change values. 
load <= '1' after 100 ns;

accu_inst : entity work.accumulator
port map(
    clk => clk,
    raz => raz,
    load => load,
    data_in => data_in,
    data_out => data_out,
    acc15 =>  acc15,   
    accz=> accz
);

end behav;
```